# Ansible copying ssh public key from one account to another using

Tags: ansible

I am facing a problem of copying ssh key between two accounts on a remote server. I have remote server called "rmt", on rmt I have one account called "clado" i want to copy the `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` (on rmt) to `/home/clado/.ssh/authorized_keys` (on rmt) using Ansible.

I got this sample code:

```
- name: Set authorized key in alternate location
  authorized_key:
    user: charlie
    state: present
    key: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/charlie/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

But it is using the local `/home/charlie/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

Comment: if you are picking it from /root/.ssh/authorized than replace home/charlie/.ssh/id_rsa.pub from /root/.ssh/authorized_keyd and do with it with sudo . Use become: true argument in your task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But it is using the local('/home/charlie/.ssh/id_rsa.pub').

All lookup plugins work locally on the Ansible control machine.

You can fetch the contents of a remote file with [`slurp` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html), for example:

```
- name: Fetch authorized key from alternate location
  slurp:
    src: /home/other_user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  register: slurped_key_b64

- name: Ensure the fetched key is set for charlie
  authorized_key:
    user: charlie
    state: present
    key: "{{ slurped_key_b64.content | b64decode }}"
```

<sup>Customise the details, because your description and your code don't match.</sup>

But generally this flow doesn't make much sense from system management point of view. Assign the key from the control machine.

Answer (score 0):

if you are picking it from 
`/root/.ssh/authorized`
than replace home
`/charlie/.ssh/id_rsa.pub from /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`

and do with it with sudo . Use `become: true`
 argument in your task.